is there a civic and/or moral duty or obligation for one to be an 'active citizen in a democracy'?
reading a post on daily nous the other day, i saw the comment by columbia college chicago professor s. asma that

students cannot just learn about game design and digital editing, and not learn about Islam, China, the history of slavery, logic or writing. That purely vocational approach is embarrassingly out of touch with what students need. [...] Without liberal arts, students will lack [...] the social, cultural and historical knowledge to be active citizens in a democracy.

which does not necessarily assume that people must be active citizens in a democracy - the point may be that, if they so choose, they need to have some tools (?) to do so - but it raised the title question for me
i'm reminded of dewey's  account of aristotle, according to which

[...] Aristotle again makes a distinction of superior and inferior even within those living the life of reason. For there is a distinction in ends and in free action, according as one's life is merely accompanied by reason or as it makes reason its own medium. That is to say, the free citizen who devotes himself to the public life of his community, sharing in the management of its affairs and winning personal honor and distinction, lives a life accompanied by reason. But the thinker, the man who devotes himself to scientific inquiry and philosophic speculation, works, so to speak, in reason, not simply by [it]. Even the activity of the citizen in his civic relations, in other words, retains some of the taint of practice, of external or merely instrumental doing. This infection is shown by the fact that civic activity and civic excellence need the help of others; one cannot engage in public life all by himself. But all needs, all desires imply, in the philosophy of Aristotle, a material factor; they involve lack, privation; they are dependent upon something beyond themselves for completion. A purely intellectual life, however, one carries on by himself, in himself; such assistance as he may derive from others is accidental, rather than intrinsic. In knowing, in the life of theory, reason finds its own full manifestation; knowing for the sake of knowing irrespective of any application is alone independent, or self-sufficing. Hence only the education that makes for power to know as an end in itself, without reference to the practice of even civic duties, is truly liberal or free.

so that political partaking would be regarded not as a constituent part of flourishing/eudaimonia, but rather a distraction in its way, and so it seems to follow that there would be no such duty or obligation; of course then i'm interested in knowing about other frameworks' and viewpoints' answers, in either direction

Citizens have a practical incentive to be active and participating in the common affairs of the republic since it affects them and can have a say. Full-time participation is not necessary though

I suspect that if you drilled down a little deeper, you'd find that when this person says "active citizens in a democracy" he or she really means "people who will work to advance my political agenda".

Why wouldn't one want people who will help them advance their political agenda?
